# Lua insert mode mappings are pasting the rhs in buffer instead of executing them

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, lua

In my `init.lua`, I've got some keys bound to some actions in insert mode.

e.g.:

```
vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-j>', '<Plug>(easymotion-bd-w)')
```

But when I press <kbd>Ctrl-e</kbd>`w`, instead of highlighting words to jump to, `<Plug>(easymotion-bd-w)` is actually written in the buffer.

If it matters, I'm using kickstart.nvim.

Here's a screenshot that illustrates the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-j>', '<Plug>(easymotion-bd-w)', { remap = true} )
```

Comment: Is the solution proposed working for you? How can we help you further? If it is working may be could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)